# Where to put Service/Data Access Classes in a Zend Framework App

Tags: zend-framework, data-access-layer, doctrine-orm

I originally wanted to find out how to access the Doctrine 2's Entity Manager from within Entity Classes. But I saw another question [Using EntityManager inside Doctrine 2.0 entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108291/using-entitymanager-inside-doctrine-2-0-entities), and learnt that I should be using a service class. I wonder where should I put in a Zend Framework Application? Also is it also called a DAO (Data Access Object)? I am thinking of naming it DAO instead of Service as Service sounds alot like something for external sites to use (like Web Service)?

I am thinking something like `Application_Models_DAO_User`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service classes are part of the autoloader mapping. Like `Application_Model_Something` can be found in *application/models*, it's the same for services.

An application service `Application_Service_Something` should be located at: *application/services/Something.php*

When you use service classes inside modules, for example `Blog_Service_Something` they need to be located at: *application/modules/blog/services/Something.php*

I think classes like entity managers shouldn't be part of your controllers nor your models, but located in service classes.

Comment: Of course, you can customize your own autoloader mapping with [Resource Autloaders](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html) of which `Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader`, typically created in `Bootstrap`, is an example.