# doctrine extra lazy load doesn't work as expected with count

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I have an entity `Shop` and a related entity `ShopProduct`, with the following relation:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ShopProduct", mappedBy="shopid", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
 */
private $products;
```

In a twig template I want to access the **count** of `products`, so I access

```
{{ entity.getProducts().count }}
```

But when using the symfony2 profiler to look at number and content of the queries, I see that a full select is issued, instead of the `COUNT` I would expect (based on [the documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html)).

Issuing the full select for each of the `Shop`s results in a memory usage of 250Mb+ and a page load time of 30+ seconds, which is undesired.

After adding the `fetch="EXTRA_LAZY"` I've cleared the doctrine caches.

Am I overlooking something, using the wrong approach or misunderstanding the docs?

[edit]

```
doctrine/annotations                v1.1
doctrine/cache                      v1.0
doctrine/collections                v1.1
doctrine/common                     2.4.0-RC1
doctrine/data-fixtures              dev-master eef10f6
doctrine/dbal                       2.3.3
doctrine/doctrine-bundle            v1.2.0-beta1
doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle   dev-master 275540d
doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle dev-master 99c0192
doctrine/inflector                  v1.0
doctrine/lexer                      v1.0
doctrine/migrations                 dev-master e1f6efc
doctrine/orm                        2.3.3
```

Comment: some extra twig tip: use `entity.products.count` instead. That will automatically search of the best way to get the `products` property

Comment: That's what I originally tried, unfortunately it results in the same # and type of queries and load time. I can't imagine that's the best way ;)

Comment: @TheRookie what version of the ORM are you using? Can you try this out of the Twig context?

Comment: @Ocramius edited my question with doctrine version info.  Getting the count from within the controller **does** fire `COUNT` queries

Comment: So this indeed looks like a twig specific problem. Are you able to check if the object hash of the collection in your controller is the same one of the collection in the twig template?

Comment: Thats's above my current knowledge level :-( Do you have a pointer in the right direction for me? Googling on 'symfony2 get collection hash' didn't get me in the right direction...

Comment: @Ocramius Could you please provide a pointer ?

Comment: I cannot, I don't use Twig. You will need to probably trace this with a step-by-step debugger.

Comment: please review my answer and ask if something is unclear, otherwise accept the answer please :)

Answer (score 14):

Just encountered the same problem and the solution was very simple:

`{{ value.getAlerts.count() }}`

instead of

`{{ value.getAlerts.count }}`

Twig must be overriding the Doctrine `count()` method meant to "Extra Lazy Load" with a variant of it's own implementation that just dumbly fetches all entities to count them.

That turned all expected SELECT * queries into COUNT(*)...

Comment: Seems like this is something Twig should fix right? Can you report your findings?

Answer (score 3):

You are not using twig's count function but the php internal one like this. Twig will execute the functions one by one ( first calling getProducts resulting in the load of all products , then count ).

```
{{ entity.getProducts().count }}
```

The getter is called automatically meaning you can just output entity.products and use twigs internal length filter to count the result ... but the result is the same ( fetching all products ).

```
{{ entity.products|length }}
```

what you're really looking for is a method setting the count on your Shop entity provided by the ShopRepository.

```
public function findAllAddCount()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('s');
    $query = $qb
        ->set('s.productCount', $qb->expr()->count('s.products'))
        ->getQuery()
   ;

   return $query->getResult();
}
```

... and add this to your entity:

```
protected $productCount;

public function getProductCount()
{
   return $this->productCount;
}

public function setProductCount($count)
{
    $this->productCount = $count;

    return $this;
}
```

Then ouput the product count in twig like this:

```
{{ entity.productCount }}
```

Comment: Hi, as far as I Know, there is no direct connection beetwen Entity and Repository. So Entity methods like getProductCount do not magicaly get result from Repository findAllAddCount(). The same with twig, you have to create extension for entity.productCount. Did I miss something?