# How to use entityManager inside Entity?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, entitymanager

I have this function in Entity class but the getDoctrine do not fond...

```
public function getObject()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    switch($this->objectType)
    {
        case 'video':
            return $em->getRepository('fdj2012AdminBundle:Video')->find($this->objectId);
            break;
        case 'default':
            return false;
            break;
    }
}
```

How to use entityManager inside my Entity ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using EntityManager inside Doctrine 2.0 entities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108291/using-entitymanager-inside-doctrine-2-0-entities).  Your entities shouldn't know about the entity manager, but rather you should pass any data/services required into your entities as and when required.

Comment: I get this from twig template... But I'm going to deepen that. Thanks

Comment: Do yo need table inheritance ? -> http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually Entity shouldn't know about EM. I use Event Listeners if I need advance logic in my Entity. When you register Listeners like services you can pass args there, like a EM or Container and get them inside Listener class.

[Symfony Doc](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html)

But I know not really good way to get EM inside Entity class. By taking global variable Kernel in Entity methods.

```
global $kernel;
if ( 'AppCache' == get_class($kernel) )
{
   $kernel = $kernel->getKernel();
}
$em = $kernel->getContainer()->get( 'doctrine.orm.entity_manager' );
```

Shame on me :(

Comment: What do you think about Entity implementing  `\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManagerAware`? when hydrating `UnitOfWork` does the job.

Answer (score -1):

In services.yml add this

```
access_manager:
  class: AppBundle\Services\EntityManager
  arguments: [ @service_container ]
```

In Manager-

```
private $_container;


public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
{
    $this->_container = $container;
}
```

To access manager-

```
        $entity2Manager = $this->_container->get('entity2_manager');
```

Comment: It is a bad practice to inject the container. Injecting the whole service container just to get the entity manager is breaking a fly on the wheel. Although this can be a quick and dirty solution in some cases, like avoiding circular references.