# Doctrine - count users in table by id

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I have 6 records in a database. 
3 from user 1, 2 from user 2 and 1 from user 3.

I want to count them by user_id so the final result would be 3. And it always returns count of all records from table. It returns 6.

My func:

```
return $this->getDeviceRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('tlu')
        ->select('COUNT(tlu.user_id)')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get maximum id inside Doctrine entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36937754/get-maximum-id-inside-doctrine-entity)

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 solutions (with groupBy or countDistinct)

```
return $this->getDeviceRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('tlu')
        ->select('COUNT(tlu.user_id)')
        ->groupBy('tlu.user_id')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

or

```
return $this->getDeviceRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('tlu')
        ->select('COUNT(tlu.user_id)')
        ->countDistinct('tlu.user_id')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Comment: I needed to add count($result) on result because it returns array with 3 objects. @RachedBCH

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can do as following

```
getResult()->count();
```

or

```
return $this->getDeviceRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('tlu')
        ->select('COUNT(tlu.user_id)')
        ->countDistinct('tlu.user_id')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleScalarResult();
```