# How can I self delete an object in Doctrine2?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

The scenario is quite simple to explain with an example:

```
public function setValue($value)
{
    if ($value == 0) {
          // DELETE ME
    }

    return $this;
}
```

I'm probably going to use a workaround (i.e.: deleting the object after the call to `setValue`, but I'd like to encapsulate this business logic within the method)

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you'd probably require access to the EntityManager which you don't have within an entity (and for good reason, just as one of many examples see [this example of how to get the Manager within an entity anway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684745/get-entitymanager-inside-an-entity) - it's VERY BAD PRACTISE).

So I suggest to follow your 'workaround' - to keep it away from other stuff I suggest to use the [Doctrine event system](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html) - but it's depending on your personal flavor.

Comment: Yeah... I wouldn't want to go the ugly way (the bad practice you mention)... It'd be nice to have somewhat of a "to be deleted" mark on the object itself which could be set from within though...

Comment: this can be easily achieved with a listener, check my link to the event system