# Make a list field editable when this field is a many_to_one type using in Sonata-project Symfony

Tags: sonata-admin, many-to-one, symfony-3.2

My entity

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Estat", inversedBy="temes")
 */
private $estat;


public function setEstat(\Ncd\ForumBundle\Entity\Estat $estat = null)
{
    $this->estat = $estat;

    return $this;
}
```

My admin

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{

    //$estats=$this->getEstatsPossibles()->toArray();
    $estats=array();
    foreach($this->getEstatsPossibles() as $estat)
    {
        $estats[$estat->getId()]=$estat->getNom();
    }

    $listMapper
      ->add('estat', 'choice',['editable' => true,'choices'=> $estats])
```

I'd like to make estat field editable in the list grid. Doing it on this way I get make it editable, a combobox appears but when I chose an option I get an exception because setEstat function of my entity does not recive an Estat entity, but a string (the array's key).

Trying

```
->add('estat', 'many_to_one',['editable' => true,'choices'=> $estats])
```

Only appears a link to the entity without any possibility to change.

Is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

Waiting for a better and cleaner solution I'v solved this injecting an entityManager in my entity following the solution of this answer:
[Get entityManager inside an Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684745/get-entitymanager-inside-an-entity)

Then, in my entity I've changed setEstat function:

```
public function setEstat( $estat = null)
{
    if (is_object($estat) &&   get_class($estat)=='Ncd\ForumBundle\Entity\Estat')
    {
        $this->estat=$estat;

    } else {
        $estat_o=$this->em->getRepository('Ncd\ForumBundle\Entity\Estat')->find((int)$estat);
        $this->estat = $estat_o;
    }


    return $this;
}
```