# Can a Doctrine entity read itself?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, datamapper, single-responsibility-principle

just curious .. I have some code like so:

```
//$em is EntityManager of Doctrine
//$className is a type that uses polymorphism (subtype of a parent type)
$pricing = $em->getRepository($className)->findOneBy(array(
    'active' => true,
    'product_id' => (int) $this->id
));

//gets serialization of certain variables of $className
return $pricing->getSerialization();
```

But ... instead of calling `findOneBy` *outside* of `$className`, can I move `getSerialization()` method inside the Entity (which is $className), and return class-parameters from there?

I imagine it is not possible, since Entity cannot read itself.  Correct?

The problem I am trying to solve is. ... In the example above Entity is populated via Doctrine and then it returns data.  Therefore *I have to use another class to populate the entity*.  Without Doctrine I know it's possible to do things such as read data from inside the Entity i.e. via `mysqli`, and then return properties directly or via a method.  In other words, do I absolutely need another location (class/function/method outside of Entity) to populate the entity?

Sample Entity looks like so

```
class Pricing
{
    function getSerialization(){}

    /**
     * @var integer @Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     *      @Id
     *      @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;
    //etc, a typical Doctrine Entity
}
```

Comment: No.  Doctrine entities are just plain objects and cannot load themselves from the database.  What you could do is create a method ProductRepository::getSerializedPricing($productId).  But sticking to the code you have is probably the best.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the instance of an entity class can read itself.
But I guess your question should have been: *"Can a Doctrine entity load and read itself?"*. The answer to that is no...

Loading of entities is managed by doctrine internals. If you would want the entity classes to load themselves it would mean injecting an `EntityManager` into the entity class.

This is a bad idea, I [quote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4109458/1697459) @BryanM. his answer on another **stack**overflow question that covers this nicely:

> It is not a good idea to allow an entity object to rely on the entity manager. It ties the entity to the persistence layer, which was a problem Doctrine 2 was specifically trying to solve. The biggest hassle in relying on the entity manager is that it makes your model hard to test in isolation, away from the database.
>
> You should probably be relying on service objects to handle the operations that rely on the entity manager.

It means you need to take care of loading entities externally. I still don't see the problem with `getSerialization`. It can be inside the Entity class and can be used after the entity is loaded right?

If you want to do loading and serializing at once I would suggest making a `PricingService` in which you inject the repository or entity manager and where you define a public methods that does all that. For example:

```
<?php

use Application\Entity\Pricing;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class PricingService
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    protected $entityManager;

    /**
     * @param EntityManager $entityManager
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }
    
    /**
     * @return EntityRepository;
     */
    protected function getRepository()
    {
        return $this->entityManager->getRepository(`Application\Entity\Pricing`);
    }

    /**
     * @param $params
     * @return array 
     */
    public function findSerializedBy($params)
    {
        $pricing = $this->getRepository()->findOneBy($params);
        return $pricing->getSerialization();
    }
}
```

Now you can work with your PricingService directly:

```
$serializedPricing = $pricingService->findSerializedBy(array(
    'active' => true,
    'product_id' => (int) $this->id
));
```

You can of course generalize your service by adding another parameter with the `$classname`.

Comment: @Dennis Did creating a Service like this solve your issue? Or was this not the answer that you were looking for? :D